# How does Casting work in PHP?

Tags: php, casting, integer, octal

What doesn't this work:

```
(int)08 == (int)09==0
```

But this and this does?

```
(int)07==7 
(int)06==6
```

Comment: I would actually take try make your question a little more topical and then put your example in the question...

Comment: I tried to give it a go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

08 is in octal base (because it starts with a 0), hence it is invalid. [See the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Answer (score 11):

because `08` and `09` are not valid octal numbers. [see warning in docs](http://docs.php.net/types.integer).

Answer (score 1):

You're type casting an invalid number in octal base.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Syntax error
//(int)08 == (int)09==0

// This works
(int)08==0;
(int)09==0;

// This also works
(int)08 == ((int)09==0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are explicitly typecasting using `(int)`

Better use `intval().`

Answer (score -1):

> To use hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x.

Therefore,

```
 $num = (int)0x9
 $num == 9
```